# Same queries giving different results

Tags: sql, database, pgadmin

So for an assignment at school, we had to extract a count from a database. The question was as follows,

--19) How many airports in a timezone name containing 'Europe' are used as a source airport (source_airport_id) for a route that has aircraft that have a wake of 'M' or 'L'

This was the code I came up with,

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT airports.id) FROM airports WHERE timezone_name LIKE '%Europe%' AND id IN
(SELECT source_airport_id FROM routes WHERE id IN 
(SELECT id FROM route_aircrafts WHERE aircraft_id IN 
(SELECT id FROM aircrafts WHERE wake_size IN ('M', 'L'))));
```

it returned 544, while the professors answer returned 566.

```
SELECT count (DISTINCT airports.id)
FROM airports, routes, route_aircrafts, aircrafts

WHERE airports.id = routes.source_airport_id
AND routes.id = route_aircrafts.route_id
AND aircrafts.id = route_aircrafts.aircraft_id

AND airports.timezone_name LIKE'%Europe%'
AND aircrafts.wake_size IN ('M', 'L'); --566
```

To me, those two should be doing the same thing and I can't understand why the answers are different.

Comment: Just an FYI: If your instructor is using comma syntax for JOINs, you might should find an instructor with more recent experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the same answer in your query you need:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT airports.id) FROM airports WHERE timezone_name LIKE '%Europe%' AND id IN
(SELECT source_airport_id FROM routes WHERE id IN 
(SELECT route_id FROM route_aircrafts WHERE aircraft_id IN 
(SELECT id FROM aircrafts WHERE wake_size IN ('M', 'L'))));
```

You'd used the primary ID field rather than the foreign key route_id. You were getting an approximately similar result because there must be a significant overlap in the values.

Comment: If you can, avoid using sub-selects to filter. Use `JOIN`s instead. Sub-selects will destroy your performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something along the lines of:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT airports.id)
FROM airports 
INNER JOIN routes ON airports.id = routes.source_airport_id
INNER JOIN route_aircrafts ON routes.id = route_aircrafts.route_id
INNER JOIN aircrafts ON route_aircrafts.aircraft_id = aircrafts.id
    AND aircrafts.wake_size IN ('M', 'L')
WHERE airports.timezone_name LIKE '%Europe%'
```

*Explanation:*

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT airports.id)
```

You don't want to count duplicate `airports.id`s more than once.

```
FROM airports
```

This is the main table you're counting from. All other tables build from this one.

```
INNER JOIN routes ON airports.id = routes.source_airport_id
```

`INNER JOIN` will only include rows that match in both tables. Matching on `airports.id` and `routes.source_airport_id`.

```
INNER JOIN route_aircrafts ON routes.id = route_aircrafts.route_id
```

`INNER JOIN` will only include rows that match in both tables. Matching on `routes.id` and `route_aircrafts.route_id`.

```
INNER JOIN aircrafts ON route_aircrafts.aircraft_id = aircrafts.id
AND aircrafts.wake_size IN ('M', 'L')
```

Same thing with the `INNER JOIN`s above. We've added an additional filter for `wakes`. For an `INNER JOIN`, this filter can also be performed in the `WHERE` clause without changing the results. Putting filters in the `JOIN` keeps the intent together (and the optimizer will likely filter this way anyway). For an `OUTER JOIN`, filtering in the `JOIN` vs filtering in the `WHERE` can possibly return different results (depending on your data).

```
WHERE airports.timezone_name LIKE '%Europe%'
```

Now we are filtering the entire resultset by the `timezone_name` from the base table of `airports`.

When working with SQL, it's important to think of your data in *SETS*. This will help you write more performant, and less programatic, queries.